# Multiplicative inverses in modular arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given a number $n$ and modulus $m$, the modular inverse is the number $x$ such that 
$$ xa \equiv 1 \mod m.$$

If I have only the number $a$, is it possible to find all the numbers $m$, for which $a$ has a multiplicative inverse?

And if it's possible, this algorithm how is computationally complex?

Comment: This happens exactly for all numbers comprime with $a$. So, for example you can pick $m=a+1$, having a computaional complexity of $O(1)$.

Comment: You seem to use $a$ and $n$ for the same thing. Is that right?

Comment: Yeah, thank to pointing me, I've just corrected the question

Comment: Given $a$, if you pick an $m$ that shares no factors with it, then there exist integers $x$ and $y$ for which $ax + my = 1$; modulo $m$, this means that $ax = 1$ i.e. that $x$ serves as the modular inverse for $a$. This follows from [**Bézout's identity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) and the (non-unique) $x$ and $y$ can be found using the **extended GCD algorithm**.

Comment: My question is how to find all the m for wich a have the multiplicative inverse

Comment: LIST=[]; FOR $m=1$ to $\infty$; IF $\gcd(a,m)=1$; PUT $m$ into LIST; END IF; END FOR. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes it's clear, but it was clear also at your first comment :-) . I was replying to the user Benjamin Dickman.
However thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer summarizing the comments and addressing the computational complexity.

You can't find "all the numbers $m$" since there are infinitely many, so suppose you are interested in those less than some $M$. You need to look at all the integers less than $M$, which bounds your time as $\Omega(M)$.

You can compute the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $m$ in time $O(\log (a)$. Since $a$ is fixed that's essentially a constant in your analysis, so the time is $O(M)$.

In an actual application there may be ways to bypass computing  all those greatest common divisors and speed things up. You could factor $a$, then use an Eratosthenes  sieve to cross off all the integers less than $M$ that share a prime divisor of $a$.